# Select data from excel and paste it in webpage fileds

Tags: java

I'm looking a way to take a string (for example from a cell in excel, but it does not have to be from excel) and paste it in a form in a web page.
I prefer to do it in java but I didn't find anywhere how it's can be done in java.
Which way it's can be done?
Thanks.
Shaked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). It lets you pre-define a set of actions for a browser, including going to a certain page, fiddling with form fields, and submitting the form.

It is possible to program this with Java, and as you may know, you can also use Java to read from files on your computer.

Comment: ... and apache POI for processing the excel

Comment: Selenium if for firefox and I need it to chrome.
I know that there is a way to convert it to chrome but I like to know where I can read about it.